# "Error occurred" facebook login in ios application

Tags: ios, facebook

i have integrate the facebook sdk for post something on facebook.Its working for only single facebook-id which is used for integrating facebook it in my application, not working for other.
this is my code

```
-(IBAction)postOnFacebook:(id)sender {
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Sharing Tutorial", @"name",@"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",                                @"Allow your users to share stories on Facebook from your app using the iOS SDK.", @"description",@"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/share/", @"link",@"http://i.imgur.com/g3Qc1HN.png", @"picture",nil];

// Show the feed dialog
[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
                                       parameters:params
                                          handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
                                              if (error) {
                                                  // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                                                  // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                                                  NSLog(@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description);
                                              } else {
                                                  if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                                                      // User cancelled.
                                                      NSLog(@"User cancelled.");
                                                  } else {
                                                      // Handle the publish feed callback
                                                      NSDictionary *urlParams = [self parseURLParams:[resultURL query]];

                                                      if (![urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]) {
                                                          // User cancelled.
                                                          NSLog(@"User cancelled.");

                                                      } else {
                                                          // User clicked the Share button
                                                          NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Posted story, id: %@", [urlParams valueForKey:@"post_id"]];
                                                          NSLog(@"result %@", result);
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }];

}


// A function for parsing URL parameters returned by the Feed Dialog.
- (NSDictionary*)parseURLParams:(NSString *)query {
NSArray *pairs = [query componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for (NSString *pair in pairs) {
    NSArray *kv = [pair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
    NSString *val =
    [kv[1] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    params[kv[0]] = val;
}
return params;
}
```

this meth
Error come when i use another id for login

[image: Error come when other facebook id use]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the publish_action permission which can be made availaible to all users only after approval from facebook.

Currently you might have created the facebook app in your account and with that account id you will be able to post to facebook. This is because of the reason that facebook gives all the permissions to users who are added as Developers/Testers in the App Dashboard.

You can add people to your app as Testers/Developers by following the steps as described below

You'll need to be an admin to give someone a role on your Page. If the person is your Facebook friend:

```
Go to your Page and tap More.
Tap Edit Settings > Page Roles.
Tap Add Person to Page. You may need to enter your password to continue.
Begin typing a friend's name and tap their name from the list that appears.
Tap to choose a role > Add.
```

If the person isn't your Facebook friend, you can log into Facebook from a computer and add them by entering their email address.

Depending on their settings, the person may receive a notification or an email when you give them a role.

These users who are added will have all the permission that you are requesting.

If you want the permissions to be availaible to everyone, your facebook app should be approved and for that you have to submit your app to facebook for review. The guidelines for facebook app submision can be found from the following link
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understood your question. 
But, for what I'm seeing. If you have created app at facebook (to integrate with your iOS app) you have to use the facebook app ID only, presented at Facebook.

Or, if this error is because you are trying to login with another facebook account. This is happening probably because you did not publish your app yet (facebook app). So it's not available to everyone, but its ok because you probably don't want to make it available right now. So you just need to go to the left menu at Roles in your facebook app page and add test users (the account that you're trying to login) or add as administrator.